# linq 'not in' query not resolving to what I expect

Tags: linq

I've written the following query in Linq:

```
var res =  dc.TransactionLoggings
             .Where(
                x => !dc.TrsMessages(y => y.DocId != x.DocId)
              ).Select(x => x.CCHMessage).ToList();
```

This resolves to the following:

```
SELECT [t0].[CCHMessage]
FROM [dbo].[TransactionLogging] AS [t0]
WHERE NOT (EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [dbo].[TrsMessages] AS [t1]
    WHERE [t1].[DocId] <> [t0].[DocId]
    ))
```

Which always returns null

Basiaclly what I'm trying to write is the following :

```
Select cchmessage
from transactionlogging
where docid not in (select docid from trsmessages)
```

Any suggestions on what's wrong with my LINQ statment?

Comment: Did you really mean to have `!=` in the TrsMessages argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var res =  dc.TransactionLoggings
             .Where(tl => !dc.TrsMessages.Any(trsm=> trsm.DocId == tl.DocId))
             .Select(x => x.CCHMessage).ToList();
```

or

```
   var trsMessagesDocId = dc.TrsMessages.Select(trsm => trsm.DocId).ToList();

   var res = dc.TransactionLoggins
                .Where(tl => !trsMessagesDocId.Contains(tl.DocId))
                .Select(tl => tl.CCHMEssage)
                .ToList();
```